# Why does the "date -u" command show time 25 seconds ahead of "export TZ=UTC; date"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, time-zone, clockspeed

I am running clockspeed-0.62 (DJB software) on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander). I have setup time zones so that `/usr/share/zoneinfo` is a link to `/usr/share/right`, and I have setup an up-to-date `/etc/leapsecs.dat` file, that is, 25 leapseconds.

Why does the `date -u` command show time 25 seconds ahead `export TZ=UTC; date` and how can it be fixed?

```
root@ubuntu:~# date; (export TZ=UTC; date); date -u
Mon Feb  3 22:33:56 CET 2014
Mon Feb  3 21:33:56 UTC 2014
Mon Feb  3 21:34:21 UTC 2014
```